# sign up newsletter form

Tags: wordpress, image, overlay

I need to change a mailchimp form to a more basic form which will just send an email rather than involving mailchimp.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this, as I need it styling the same but just so that it emails to my client rather than needing all MailChimp api's etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big questions are:

1. Why do you want to avoid MailChimp?
2. How are you going to collect user information to then use it externally from Wordpress?
3. Are you trying to do this for free?

A very simple way to handle this is by setting up a [Wufoo form](http://wufoo.com) with an email notification once they sign up that will provide the information you want them to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use the PHP mail function to accomplish this.

Create a new php file and insert some very basic code like the following:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can even create a new php file named mail.php or whatever you'd like and save it as a WordPress template. Create a new page within WordPress named contact us, then select mail.php as a template. Your contact us page will now use your custom form.

**Reference:**
 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Hi thanks i'm not too sure how to do this but I'll have a look in to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My client didn't want to use MailChimp to start off with, the main problem is that the information that is being asked for isn't exactly the information my client wants to gain from people signing up but I don't know how to add in new fields i.e Telephone number.

I was hoping to put either a basic form or something in the same style as the sign up box is currently.